# Do hex-changed torrent files (*.torrent) create issues?

Tags: bittorrent

I am aware of that torrent files have the function of hash-check, but what about the files not in the *.torrent files themselves? To check torrent files, it needs the original hash checksum values of the torrent files themselves.

For example, anyone can hex edit like marking 00 codes or anything to create torrent files.

Torrent files can be changed in this way, but I found they can be run by torrent client with no warning. After that, i wonder if torrent files are already changed by hex edit, or whether they are making any kind of changes to check, hash files in torrents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each torrent has an unique ID called the *infohash*, and you can only download files from peers who seed the exact same infohash. If the infohash is different, even though the files themselves might be the same, that still makes it an entirely new torrent.

The infohash is directly based on the `info` dict structure inside the .torrent file. All `.torrent` files are structured data, encoded in the *bencode* format. Converted to text, [this Ubuntu torrent](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent) – for example – would look like this:

```
{
    "announce": "http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce"
    "announce-list": [
        0: [
            0: "http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce"
        ]
        1: [
            0: "http://ipv6.torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce"
        ]
    ]
    "comment": "Ubuntu CD releases.ubuntu.com"
    "creation date": "1469103218"
    "info": {
        "length": "1513308160"
        "name": "ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso"
        "piece length": "524288"
        "pieces": bytes [
            92 90 ed e1 86 46 26 1c 7f 40 02 6f 60 e1 17 1f a8 4b 3b ce 81 d2 c2 30
            13 d5 9c d3 b7 14 d9 d8 4e e3 21 d8 04 44 be 97 db ce c0 87 b3 d0 26 22
            c0 e1 80 d6 ec 83 75 40 86 6b 8d 88 9b bf ea db ad 49 d8 54 e4 69 ba b6
            bc ca dd ed b0 02 5c 74 22 1b bf 00 97 89 b1 b3 fa f8 21 45 5e ff 0c 65
            8f c3 00 a8 23 cd bd be 5d e5 5e 7e 2f 32 66 e3 0c 68 b3 09 de d3 1d 12
            c7 32 6b 92 2e ce 3d 67 79 dc e0 5c 53 f2 a3 a8 84 55 b8 38 c4 26 2d ac
            ... (57596 more bytes)
        ]
    }
}
```

Notice how the `info: { ... }` structure describes all the *contents* of the torrent – file names, sizes, the hash of every 'piece', and sometimes things like the "private torrent" bit. If your edits change this part in any way, this will result in the infohash changing, and you won't be able to download it from old peers.

But if you change something *outside* the `info` dict, however, there shouldn't be any problems at all – provided, of course, that the edits actually make sense. For example, you can freely change the trackers listed in `announce-list`, edit the `comment`, and maybe even add additional fields.

That said, instead of blindly hex-editing the raw file, why not use a program that actually understands the structure – e.g. an actual "torrent editor"? Those definitely exist.

And finally, if your edits result in the file no longer having valid *bencode* syntax, that will definitely "create issues", as in programs won't be able to load the .torrent file anymore. This includes, for example, making a piece of text longer or shorter. (In the *raw* format that your hex-editor shows, notice how each string is prefixed by its length, e.g. `5:hello`. They must always match.)